# How to trigger tooltip when we tab focus over it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to trigger a tooltip for accessibility. Hence want to know how I can trigger it on keyboard tabbing and maybe an additional Enter key if required.

Currently, the below code triggers tooltip when I hover over "Close" using the mouse

```
<p id="closep" class="ibm-ind-link margin-right-22px margin-left-16px ibm-fright">
    <a id="exit_tour_CTA" data-widget="tooltip" tabindex="6" data-contentid="closett"
       class="ibm-close-link fontSize16" aria-label="Exit Tour">Close</a>
</p>
<div id="closett" class="ibm-tooltip-content">
    <span style="color:white;">Exit Tour</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

(in case if you are working with bootstrap)
try by adding data-trigger="focus"